# Вопрос по построению бд

Tags: mysql, база-данных

У меня есть задание.

> Вы работаете в бюро по трудоустройству. Вашей задачей является
>   отслеживание финансовой стороны работы компании. Деятельность бюро
>   организована следующим образом: бюро готово искать работников для
>   различных работодателей и вакансии для ищущих работу специалистов
>   различного профиля. При обращении к вам клиента-работодателя его
>   стандартные данные (название, вид деятельности, адрес, телефон)
>   фиксируются в базе данных. При обращении к вам клиента-соискателя его
>   стандартные данные (фамилия, имя, отчество, квалификация, профессия,
>   иные данные) также фиксируются в базе данных. По каждому факту
>   удовлетворения интересов обеих сторон составляется документ. В
>   документе указываются соискатель, работодатель, должность и
>   комиссионные (доход бюро).
>
> Сущности Работодатели (Код работодателя, Название, Вид деятельности,
>   Адрес, Телефон). Соискатели (Код соискателя, Фамилия, Имя, Отчество,
>   Квалификация, Вид деятельности, Иные данные, Предполагаемый размер
>   заработной платы). Сделки (Код соискателя, Код работодателя,
>   Должность, Комиссионные).
>
> ЧАСТЬ 2 Развитие постановки задачи.
>   Оказалось, что база данных не
>   совсем точно описывает работу бюро. В базе фиксируется только сделка,
>   а информация по открытым вакансиям не хранится. Кроме того, для
>   автоматического поиска вариантов необходимо вести справочник «Виды
>   деятельности».

Я сделал 1 часть 
http://c2n.me/3DtSlP6 - вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Преподаватель сказал что она правильная, но никак не знаю как сделать 2 часть. Если есть идеи подскажите, или нарисуйте пожалуйста

Comment: Добавте поле сделка и отслеживайте по нему состояние сделка открыта/закрыта. Создайте таблицу виды деятельности и свяжите ее с таблицей клиенты соискоискатели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Model]

На самом деле в Интернете полно уже готовых решений.

Данная картинка взята [отсюда](http://access.avorut.ru/load/bazy_dannykh_ms_access/kontrolnye_raboty_po_bazam_dannykh_ms_access/skachat_bazu_dannykh_access_bjuro_po_trudoustrojstvu/3-1-0-225)

Структура таблицы «Агенты бюро»: Код агента, Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, Телефон.

Структура таблицы «Вакансии»: № по порядку, код работодателя, пол, должность, образование, квалификация, наличие водительских прав, владение ПК, иностранные языки, должностные обязанности, зарплата,  условия труда, иная информация, дата заполнения, открытая вакансия.

Структура таблицы «Должности»: код должности, наименование должности.

Структура таблицы «Работодатели»: код работодателя, название, вид деятельности, адрес, телефон, ФИО контакта.

Структура таблицы «Сделки»: номер сделки, код соискателя, код вакансии, агент, дата составления, комиссионные, оплачено, дата оплаты.

Структура таблицы «Соискатели»: код соискателя, фамилия, имя, отчество, дата рождения, пол, должность, образование, квалификация, предполагаемая зарплата, иная информация, дата заполнения.